# Removing part of the URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

Here's my application's structure :

```
- app/
    - routes/
    - views/
    - start.php
- public/
    - css/
    - js/
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
```

I'm using `Slim` as a PHP framework.

At the moment, since my `index.php`  is in the `public`  directory, my URLs have to look something like this :

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/public/about
```

How can I rewrite the URL so that this is equivalent to the above :

```
 http://www.mywebsite/about
```

I've read about this and saw something like that as a common answer :

```
 RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,R]
```

I tried it, but it's not working. This is the error I'm getting :

```
The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
```

Comment: You wrote `RewriteEngine On` before using it, right ? If not, add it. Also try this once, `RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]`, and tell the updated URL you are seeing in browser.

Comment: I've seen people using things similar to this but have you tried using just [L] instead of [NC,L,R]? Just a thought as I've seen multiple using just [L] but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /public/$1 [NC,L]
```